# Result from printing statement and if statement differ

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a beginner at Java. I came across a question where a teen's age ranges from 13 - 19. There are 2 int values, and I'm supposed to print true if one is a teen, but print false if both are teens.

```
if ((a >= 13 && a <= 19) && (b >= 13 && b <= 19)) {
  out.println(false);

} 
  out.println(true);
```

With this code, I was able to generate the right output:

(13, 99) -> expected: true >> run: true

(16, 9) -> expected: true >> run: true

(13, 19) -> expected: false >> run: false

But with this one in particular, I can't: (99, 99) -> expected: false >> run: true.

Now if I try to print it out as a statement:

`System.out.println((99 >= 13 && 99 <= 19) && (99 >= 13 && 99 <= 19));`

It prints out false. Why is that?

Comment: You are *always* printing `true`. You're missing an `else`.

Comment: You only print `false` when the value of both `a` and `b` are in the 13-19 range. Given that both of those variables in your last test aren't in that range, why are you expecting it to print `true`? You may have to review the logic of your `if` statement if you want `false` when only one is a teen and the other not.

Comment: `(a >= 13 && a <= 19) && (b >= 13 && b <= 19)` is going to be false, therefore it's not going inside the if statement because 99 is NOT less than or equal to 19.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

i hope now you will able to understand the concept of Logical AND (&&) :-

```
Condition 1 Condition2  Output
true        true        true
true        false       false
false       true        false
false       false       false
```

one the TRUE + TRUE Output will be TRUE otherwise output will be FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

True &True =True.

True &(anything other than true)=false